# ASP.net MVC web api Schedule Events

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Ok so here is what I am looking for, I am trying to write a program where someone sends a request to a server but specifies a time of day they want that request processed.  Is there a way to schedule an event to trigger a particular time of day on a server?

I have looked around for resources and can't seem to find anything letting me know if this is even possible.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should save that events on database and have a background a process (a windows service or a scheduled task would do the trick) running events at the specific time.

Don't think you were able to do it just with a web module and if you do, probably won't be a very recommended approach :)

Answer (score 0):

I would split this functionality into two parts:

- Web server that enqueues a request
- Processing engine that is responsible for job execution and time tracking. This can be a Windows service with a persistent storage to save the results and progress.

Otherwise a webserver may say adios after couple hundred of requests.